# How can I connect a PIA or VIA chip to the Apple IIc?

Tags: apple-ii, hardware-mods

I have an early Apple IIc, model A2S4000 with the 342-0272 motherboard
and ROM 255. (I am considering upgrading the ROM, perhaps with a
switch that would let me switch between different ROM versions.)

I'm thinking I'd like to connect something like a Motorola MC6821 PIA
(4 I/O addresses) or MOS 6522 VIA (16 I/O addresses) to my Apple IIc.
I pick these chips as typical examples; the general idea applies to
anything similar, such as another ACIA or whatever.

(Note that this question is not looking for XY challenges proposing
ways to connect I/O through means that don't resemble direct access to
an IC on the system bus; that's not what I'm investigating right now.)

On a "non-c" Apple II this is no big deal; just plop the chip on a
board with whatever additional logic you need, plug it in and Bob's
your uncle. The Apple II even provides dedicated address space and
decoding for the chip's I/O addresses and ROM, if ROM is necessary.
(It's not in my case, though it would be nice to have if possible.)

However the IIc doesn't have actual slots, and much of the address
space is allocated to internal hardware. This leads to the following
questions (and perhaps others I've not thought of).

Is there any non-decoded  address space in the Apple IIc? (I.e.,
addresses that when accessed don't enable any hardware, including RAM
or ROM.) In the *Apple IIc Technical Reference Manual* [Tables B-5
through B-9](https://archive.org/stream/Apple_IIc_Technical_Reference_Manual#page/n343/mode/1up) list plenty of "Reserved" blocks, such as
$C020-$C02F (onboard I/O area) and $C0B0-$C0FF (slots 3 through 7 I/O
areas). Reading those two blocks returns semi-random values, which one
would expect if those blocks are not decoded. If there are addresses I
can safely use for my hardware, what are they? Or need I pull some
tricks with my peripheral design to disable on-board hardware (perhaps
temporarily, the way the [No-Slot Clock](https://wiki.reactivemicro.com/No-Slot_Clock) does) in order to find
address space I can use for my hardware's control and data registers?

What are my options for connecting to the address and data buses and
necessary control lines? A typical choice seems to be to build a
"shim" that goes between a chip and the board, the way the [No-Slot
Clock](https://wiki.reactivemicro.com/No-Slot_Clock) does with the ROM or the [RAM Express II A2S4000](https://www.a2heaven.com/webshop/index.php?rt=product/product&path=73&product_id=146)
does with the CPU. What are the best chips with which to do this, both
in terms of the signals available on their sockets (or board pads) and
physical clearance? Are there other options for physical connectivity?
(I am open to the idea of modifying the board to some degree, such as
via soldering connectors to it.) For example, there seems to be a full
set of unused pads around the GLU chip. How about options that bring
the lines outside of the case, to plug in to an external board?

I'll also need some sort of address decoding for my chip select. Is
there any on-board decoding I can "steal" to do part of the work, or
need I fully decode the entire address on my hardware?

Are there any other concerns here that I've missed?

Comment: Do you have a specific use case in mind? If yes, and if timing is not critical, and alternative would be to use a suitable microcontroller hooked up to one of the serial ports.

Comment: <random comment directed at nobody in particular> Cool feature by VTech in the Laser 128 was including an external expansion slot to support this sort of thing. There's a set of DIP switches to reassign internal "pseudo-slots" to external expansion boards. </end random>

Comment: @MichaelGraf One use case would be to use the same software I use on other 6502-based computers to use things like Nintendo-style game controllers and SD cards. Building a second computer to run a PIA and communicating with it over a serial port would be a lot of extra work and also significantly slower.

Comment: @cjs For a digital game controller, you might try tying into the keyboard to electrically simulate keypresses.

Comment: @cjs - You wouldn't use the microcontroller to "run a PIA". You'd use it's own built-in I/O, including things like hardware SPI for the SD card, and you'd offload low-level tasks (e.g. polling the game controllers) to the microcontroller, and transmit only useful events (e.g. button down / button up). 

If you want to connect directly to the system buses, the route I'd investigate would be a shim board attached to the CPU socket, with a 5V CPLD to handle the glue logic (maybe an ATF15xx from Microchip, they're still in production), and whatever chips you want on there.

Comment: @MichaelGraf you should make this an answer

Comment: I agree that the shim board part, with a bit of expansion, would help with two of the three main questions in my post. To avoid things getting off-topic from what I'm looking for, I've tweaked the answer to request you not suggest entirely different means, such as a separate serial device.

Comment: @cjs The reason I did suggest the serial port solution is that, for some reason, you've picked the one model out of the entire Apple II lineup which was designed *not* to be bus expandable, and are now trying to shoehorn a bus expansion into it. That's definitely possible, and the CPU socket is definitely the right place to get all the signals you need. But it somehow feels wrong ;-), like an external box connected to one of the ports would be more in keeping with the spirit of the IIc. Or I am rambling again ;-)

Comment: @MichaelGraf Well, there are good reasons to pick the IIc. For this question, it's the only model for which the question is really interesting; the rest are easy. :-P And in general, the IIc is much more compact and portable, which is particularly imprortant to me in my circumstances. That said, I do like the idea of a (small) external box or interface to the system bus, if that could be done in a nice (and fairly reliable) way.

Answer (score 8):

Ian Kim's [Mockingboard 4C](https://quick09.tistory.com/1459) shows how it is done. This card includes a 6522 VIA chip (actually a 65C22 since those are still in production) as part of the daughterboard. It connects via the CPU socket. There is also a version for the Apple IIc+.

The Apple IIc was never designed for expansion cards so your options are via the CPU socket. Applied Engineering also sold an [expansion card](https://ae.applearchives.com/apple_c/z-ram_ultra_iii/) for the Apple IIc with a Z80 processor (for CPM), clock and 1MB of extra memory. This also connected through the CPU + MMU sockets.

Comment: Unfortunately, the first link doesn't seem to "show how it's done", but rather a link to purchase the board. The second, expansion card, link is "forbidden"?

Comment: Updated the second link to work around the site's blocking of direct links.

Answer (score 4):

Physically, the simplest and most non-invasive method to connect would be the CPU socket. Most of the contemporary IIc expansions used that.

From a "virtual slot" perspective, all of the possible 7 Apple IIc virtual slots are already occupied by one or the other ROM version and tightly woven into the operating system.  (some, like slot 5, was, in the beginning, somewhat wasted to provide the developer names through some sort of easter egg , though, later it hosted the Unidisk interface). So, without major ROM modifications, you wouldn't be able to introduce a full "virtual card".

Some of the virtual slots don't seem to use their assigned address space, though, and, for example, most of the slot 7 address space ($C0F0-$C0FF) should be usable.